# How to print from MS paint without the borders?

Tags: printing

I'm trying to print to print a design to an A5 sized sticker paper. I just want the printer to print the image without margins but I can't set the margins to `0`. What do I do to achieve this?

[image: Printer Setup page]
[image: Still has margins.]

Comment: Are you sure that is due to paint? The screenshot looks as if it is part of the printer driver, and thus completely independent of paint. (In which case it would show the same screen when printing from other applications).  If it is paint, try another program to print with. Save the drawing, open it with something like windows photo viewer (the default program when double-clicking on a picture) and use print from there.

Comment: Check margin in printer property, you may have to change in there first. Does your printer support borderless printing (edge to edge)?

Comment: Hennes, I'm pretty sure it can do edge-to-edge printing. I tried scanning a magazine before (it's Canon MP250) and it printed it up to the edge of the paper I used.

John Siu, I can't set the margin property to `0`. It always gives me a decimal point when I move the focus away from the input fields.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I got it to print without borders by downloading and using the Easy-PhotoPrint EX software from [Canon's website](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/support/consumer/printers_multifunction/pixma_mp_series/pixma_mp250?selectedName=DriversAndSoftware).

[image]