# How to get print screens on Win 10 without (black) borders in MS paint?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-paint

Whenever I make a print screen from the actual window with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>PrtScn</kbd> in Windows 10 and then paste it into MS paint, I get a black border around the picture.

What is the easiest way to get a borderless picture?
Can I change some settings? Or do I have to cut out the picture manually every time?

This question is not about [printing a picture borderless](https://superuser.com/questions/503721/how-to-print-from-ms-paint-without-the-borders), it's about saving a picture without black borders.

Comment: Do you have any different results if you take the screen capture via the Snipping Tool, rather than by keystroke?

Comment: No, the border seems to be 'by design'. If I cut the target window in the Snipping Tool exactly enough, I can get the window borderless. But that's the same surgical operation like cutting the picture in MS paint.

Comment: Do you get it when you use a Window Snip in the Snipping Tool? How big is the border? When I use Window Snip, I get a fine black line, but that's because the window is actually drawn that way. If my memory serves, in previous versions of Windows, it would catch the drop shadow around the window, too, but I don't see that on my Win10 machine.

Comment: Yes. About 1 pixel. In the meantime I've found a way to reduce the visibilty of this border: Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, enter `control color` and then lower the "Color Intensity" with the slider to 0 (to the left). Unfortunately, there is still a very light grey colored border using the standard win10 theme.

Answer (score 1):

The single-pixel "border" you're trying to remove is *part* of the window. The Windows window manager is going to report that as part of the window to any automated capture tool. You're not going to find a way to remove it during the cut/capture phase.

If you were using a better graphics package (Photoshop or GIMP, for instance), you could simply reduce the canvas size by two pixels in each dimension (one on each side) and remove the line.

Comment: This tool can be a workaround: **Snagit** [link](https://www.techsmith.com/snagit.html) It offers two ways to get rid of this 1-pixel-border. The first option is to use the magnifier during the capture phase and only cut out the part without border. The second option is 'Resize Image' and 'Custom Trim'. This let you choose where (top/bottom/left/right) you want to cut how many pixels from the actual image in the Snagit-Editor. Unfortunately, this tools isn't free.

Answer (score 0):

The newest beta version 1.2.9.x of [Greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org/) offers exactly what I was looking for.

Pressing the usual <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>PrtScn</kbd>, this tool crops automatically the unwanted 1 pixel activation border from a Windows 10 window. In addition, this tool offers many choosable targets, like MS Paint, clipboard, automatically saving in a defined directory with a defined format, uploading to various internet targets (Imgur, Flicker, Dropbox etc) or send to printer, attach to e-mail etc.

Greenshot is free and open source and the newest beta is available here: https://github.com/greenshot/greenshot/tags